# Ошибка class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно, чтобы при вводе в консоль номера ячейки массива выходило соответствующее значение на экран, но появляется ошибка:

> class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Код:

```
public class Raduga {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] colors = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blu", "Dark blu", "Purple"};
    System.out.println("add number [0:6]");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    int key = Arrays.binarySearch(colors, num);
    String keyS = Integer.toString(key);
    System.out.println(keyS);
  }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно.

Comment: Можно и без этой строки обойтись `String keyS = Integer.toString(key);`  просто `key` воткнуть в `println`

Comment: А вообще проблема имено в этом коде? такое ощущение, не тут

Comment: Да изначально так и было, после решил, что из за того что значение Num - int , а [] - String.. Думал в этом ошибка, оказалось нет

Comment: ( Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at java.base/java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:141)
 at java.base/java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Arrays.java:2234)
 at java.base/java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:2174)
 at com_new.Raduga.main(Raduga.java:11)

Answer (score 1):

В [доках](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) нет метода с сигнатурой `String[], int`  и даже `Object[], int`, есть как минимум

```
binarySearch(Object[] a, Object key)
```

Это значит, что правильно в массиве из строк искать строку, а вы зачем-то пытаетесь искать число в строке, что вообще странно и не ясно чего вы хотели этим добиться.

Также перед подобного рода поиском надо отсортировать массив,  иначе результат вызова метода будет не определен

---

Пример код

```
String[] colors = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(colors, "D"));
```

Закономерно выведет: 3

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вам надо по введенному номеру элемента получить соответствующее ему значение из массива:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] colors = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blu", "Dark blu", "Purple"};
System.out.println("add number [0:6]");
int num = in.nextInt();
System.out.println(colors[num]);
```